# Using A BlockingQueue With A Servlet To Persist Objects

Tags: java, servlets, concurrency

First, this may be a stupid question, but I'm hoping someone will tell me so, and why. I also apologize if my explanation of what/why is lacking.

I am using a servlet to upload a HUGE (247MB) file, which is pipe (|) delineated. I grab about 5 of 20 fields, create an object, then add it to a list. Once this is done, I pass the the list to an OpenJPA transactional method called persistList().

This would be okay, except for the size of the file. It's taking forever, so I'm looking for a way to improve it. An idea I had was to use a BlockingQueue in conjunction with the persist/persistList method in a new thread. Unfortunately, my skills in java concurrency are a bit weak.

Does what I want to do make sense? If so, has anyone done anything like it before?

Comment: What is the purpose of the BlockingQueue? is the call to persistList() thread-safe?

Comment: Like I said, I'm still working on the idea. However, one idea is that once the BlockingQueue reaches say 1000 elements, I call drainTo() to form a list, then start a thread to call persistList() to persist everything in the list. persistList() creates an EntityManager from the factory, then loops through to commit and call flush() every n elements. I'm unsure if it's thread safe or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Servlets should respond to requests within a short amount of time. In this case, the persist of the file contents needs to be an asynchronous job, so:

1. The servlet should respond with some text about the upload job, expected time to complete or something like that.
2. The uploaded content should be written to some temp space in binary form, rather than keeping it all in memory. This is the usual way the multi-part post libraries to their work.
3. You should have a separate service that blocks on a queue of pending jobs. Once it gets a job, it processes it.
4. The 'job' is simply some handle to the temporary file that was written when the upload happened... and any metadata like who uploaded it, job id, etc.
5. The persisting service needs to upload a large number of rows, but make it appear 'atomic', either model the intermediate state as part of the table model(s), or write to temp spaces.
6. If you are writing to temp tables, and then copying all the content to the live table, remember to have enough log space and temp space at the database level.
7. If you have a full J2EE stack, consider modelling the job queue as a JMS queue, so recovery makes sense. Once again, remember to have proper XA boundaries, so all the row persists fall within an outer transaction.
8. Finally, consider also having a status check API and/or UI, where you can determine the state of any particular upload job: Pending/Processing/Completed.

Comment: Okay, I guess it wasn't that great of an idea. Unfortunately, since it's a huge upload, the servlet isn't going to be that quick: first a BufferedReader processes the file, then sends the list to the persistence service. I had the idea that I could save a bit of time by sending chunks to the persistenceService. I'll have to reread alot of what you wrote to mentally process it, though.

Comment: liked most of the answer, didn't understand step 5, though.  wouldn't using a db transaction be sufficient?

Comment: It depends on how many records are being written. In some cases, you simply cannot write everything in one transaction. The size of the commit, lock escalation, concurrency all get affected too much. One approach to dealing with that is to perform a bunch of commits, each with a moderate number of rows (clearly, a commit per row rarely makes sense.) If @Jason wants to do it that way, I was suggesting that one approach is to add a field to each row indicating that it is part of an incomplete upload.

Comment: @Jason, if your application is for the intranet, one way to do this would be to have a Form where the uploaded file is actually a UNC name or a URL to the file. This way, the POST would simply tell the server where to get the data.

Comment: I honestly liked the idea of having a service that deals with pending jobs. I just don't know how to have a service sit and wait until a file suddenly appears, then process it. Unfortunately, I don't know JMS and I'm not using a full J2EE stack (just Jetty but probably moving to Tomcat, which doesn't count either).

Comment: Ask a new SO question -- remember to indicate whether you need a single server solution or not, and to ask for a non-JMS solution if possible :)